# Implementation of arrays in F#

Tags: arrays, f#

I have a question:

```
type Diversion = Pile[]

// allPilesEmpty: Diversion -> bool
```

I'm new in F#, and I have such an implementation to do.

Could you help me how to implement allPilesEmpty function?

Thanks.

Comment: What are you asking exactly ?

Comment: Actually I'm asking for how to fill the inside of the method. Because I have many types of such functions to do, and if I manage to implement this, the other ones will be easy for me.

Comment: please come up with a question, not a task

Comment: please, it is not a task. Just I want to check inside whether all piles are empty or not. If it would be task, I would put like 20 functions

Comment: kid, this is not a question

Comment: why? :) I need this example to implement the same structure for other functions.

Comment: read that first https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  type Diversion = Pile array

  let allPilesEmpty (diversion:Diversion) =
    diversion.Length = 0
```

Something like this maybe?

Comment: Thank you vtortola :) I'll let you know for possible questions. Thanks :)

Comment: "*That is not an array, it is a list.*" Quite incorrect.

Comment: You are right, it is also an array.